# How to use a file instead of a database?

Tags: php, arrays, database, file, bigdata

I have **2** arrays. The first array contains the **correct word variants** and the second array contains **incorrect word variants**. I want to **write** them by combining into one as an array, passing in the wrong version of the words to the key and to the value of the correct version of the word. Then write them to a file and use it. I saved the contents of the array in a file, but with a new record to the same file, all the data is **cleared** and only new entries are re-written and the **old entries are deleted automatically**. I want that before writing new data to an array, the array is **checked for duplication** and if **such** is **not written** in the file with the array, then let it be written to the file **without clearing** the previous data of the file. In general, that will select a **file** or **database** for storing more than a **billion** words. Does the database have the best **speed** or file?

> Example first array:

```
$uncorrect = array
(
0 => "мувосокори",
1 => "мунаггас",
2 => "мангит",
3 => "мангития",
4 => "мунфачир",
5 => "мунфачира",
6 => "манфиатпарасти",
7 => "манфиатчу",
8 => "манфиатчуи",
9 => "манфиатхох",
10 => "манфи",
.....................
);
```

> Example second array:

```
$correct = array
(
0 => "мувосокорӣ",
1 => "мунағғас",
2 => "манғит",
3 => "манғития",
4 => "мунфаҷир",
5 => "мунфаҷира",
6 => "манфиатпарастӣ",
7 => "манфиатҷӯ",
8 => "манфиатҷӯӣ",
9 => "манфиатхоҳ",
10 => "манфӣ",
.....................
);
```

> I combined two arrays with this code:

```
$dict = array_combine($uncorrect, $correct);
```

> Example result my array with data here:

```
$dict = array (
    "мувосокори" => "мувосокорӣ",
    "мунаггас" => "мунағғас",
    "мангит" => "манғит",
    "мангития" => "манғития",
    "мунфачир" => "мунфаҷир",
    "мунфачира" => "мунфаҷира",
    "манфиатпарасти" => "манфиатпарастӣ",
    "манфиатчу" => "манфиатҷӯ",
    "манфиатчуи" => "манфиатҷӯӣ",
    "манфиатхох" => "манфиатхоҳ",
    "манфи" => "манфӣ",
    "минкор" => "минқор",
    .....................................
    );
```

> I am writing to a file with this code:

```
file_put_contents("data.json", json_encode($dict));
```

> I will get the array with this code:

```
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents("data.json"));
```

Comment: did you mean [NoSQL Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL)? Seriously, better use MongoDB or something else.. that have flat file database schema..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better off using a database for this task.

To solve your issue if you decide to keep with the file storage, the reason you are losing old entries is because you forgot to load them before adding new values.

```
// more or less something like below
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents("data.json"));
$dict = array_combine($incorrect, $correct);
$newArray = array_merge($array, $dict);
file_put_contents("data.json", json_encode($newArray));
```

This will not be efficient for billions or rows, especially if it's something that gets loaded every time a user loads a page.

Answer (score 2):

Any time you want to add new items just load the file first, then merge the new items in before saving it again. file_put_contents is going to overwrite whatever was there, so you need to get that data before running that function. Something like this:

```
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents("data.json"));
$newArray = array(
  array( "rightWord" => "wrongWord")
);
$finalArray = array_merge($newArray, $array);
file_put_contents("data.json", json_encode($finalArray));
```